# How do i use FOR in an appended array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, append

I've used this code

```
for(var i=0;i++;)
```

in my javascript code.
How ever i'm learning and not quite sure how this can be used in an array
and if its right?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please rewrite your question? Explain it a bit further. I'm reading it like 5th time and still can't figure out what's your problem. ;)

Comment: How do you wish to use the for loop with the array, to iterate through it?  What does the array contain?

Comment: sorry for the bad question. I couldn't find the right words to explain my problem. But thank you so much. I was just wondering when you can use 'for' to make an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guffa has already pointed out how a for loop works, now let me tell you why this one won't even execute:

```
for(var i=0;i++;)
```

What it does:

1. Set `i` to `0`
2. Check whether `i++` is truthy

   1. Check whether `i` is truthy > `i` is `0` > `0` is false > exit loop
   2. Post increment `i` by `1` > no effect after all

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not quite right. The three parameters in the `for` command is initialiser, condition and incrementation. Example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { ... }
```

For use with an array, you would use the array length in the condition:

```
for (var i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++) { ... }
```

This is the most common way to use the `for` command, the three parameters can contain pretty much anything so you can make really weird loops if you like. However, unusual parameters in the command will naturally make the code harder to read, to stick to the common usage if possible.

Comment: Good answer, might be worth showing the `for (var item in theArray)` syntax too, incase the "array" in question is actually an associative object.

Comment: @Guffa Also, note: this performs better: `for (var i = 0, l = theArray.length; i < l; i++) { ... }`

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Yes, but it also does something different. If the array is appended in the loop (which may very well be the case considering the question title), it will not loop all the items.

Comment: @Opoe: Well, there is always three parameters, but they are all optional, so you can even use `for(;;)`, eventhough it's pointless.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **for each** for this one. Its possible in javascript . Take a look
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: It's not supported in IE though, so you can't use it on the general web.

Comment: Yeah. I forgot to mention that. Thanks Tim for making a note.